# Select columns, excluding some which are all NA

Tags: r, dataframe, select, dplyr

Suppose I have this dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(keep = c(1, NA, 2),
                   also_want = c(NA, NA, NA),
                   maybe = c(1, 2, NA),
                   maybe_2 = c(NA, NA, NA))
```

**Edit:** In the actual dataframe there are many columns I'd like to keep, so spelling them all out isn't viable. These columns are all the columns that do not start with `maybe`. The `maybe` columns, instead, do have a common naming like `maybe`, `maybe_1` etc. that could work with `grep` or `stringr::str_detect`

I want to select `keep`, and `also_want`.  I also want any of the `maybe` columns that have values other than `NA`

```
desired_df
  keep also_want maybe
1    1        NA     1
2   NA        NA     2
3    2        NA    NA
```

I can use `select_if` to get all columns that have non-`NA` values, but then I lose `also_want`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%   
  select_if(~sum(!is.na(.)) > 0)
  keep maybe
1    1     1
2   NA     2
3    2    NA
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `dplyr` 1.0.0 you can use the `where` function inside a `select` statement to test for conditions that your variables have to satisfy, but first you specify the variables you also want to keep.

#### EDIT

I've inserted the condition that only the `"maybe"` variables have to contain values other than `NA`; before, we select every column that does not start with `"maybe"`.

```
df %>% 
  select(!starts_with("maybe"), starts_with("maybe") & where(~sum(!is.na(.)) > 0))
```

Output

```
#   keep also_want maybe
# 1    1        NA     1
# 2   NA        NA     2
# 3    2        NA    NA
```

Comment: `df` is a toy example - in reality spelling out all the "keeper" columns isn't going to work.  I've edited the question to address this.

Comment: @Greg I've edited my answer based on what you wrote in the comment and in the edit. However, if there is no condition about the "keeper" variables, you can't do anything to select them.

Comment: @Greg Just to know: the variables you want to keep mandatorily are all the variables except the ones starting with `"maybe"`?

Comment: Yes, all variables that don't start with `maybe` are to be kept regardless of their content.

Comment: @Greg Answer edited with the adjustments you specified

Answer (score 2):

following your comments, in Base-R we can use

```
df[,!apply(
    rbind(
        grepl("maybe",colnames(df)),
        !apply(df, 2, function(x) !all(is.na(x)))
    )
,2,all)]

  keep also_want maybe
1    1        NA     1
2   NA        NA     2
3    2        NA    NA
```

Or if you prefer seeing the same code all on 1 line:

```
df[,!apply(rbind(grepl("maybe",colnames(df)),!apply(df, 2, function(x) !all(is.na(x)))),2,all)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured this out.  Using `str_detect` to select all non-`maybe` columns, and then using a one-liner inside `sapply` to also select any other columns (i.e. any `maybe`  columns) that have non-`NA` values.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
  select_if(stringr::str_detect(names(.), "maybe", negate = TRUE) |
              sapply(., function(x) {
                sum(!is.na(x))
              } > 0))
  keep also_want maybe
1    1        NA     1
2   NA        NA     2
3    2        NA    NA
```